# Matplotlib multiple graphs, extra space underneath x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying mathplotlib for the first time. I want to create two separate graphs. I'm able to get both graphs to show, however, the second graph has extra space underneath the x-axis and makes the x-axis scale labels/axis label show way below. If I comment out the first graph, the extra space disappears.

I've attempted using plt.tight_layout() and that made the rest of the graph tight (labels were laying over-each other), but did not help w/ my extra space at the bottom. [see the right graph with the red marking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbkz0.png)

Note: I changed the configuration on the right graph to show the extra space, so that's why it'll look different than the ranges I included in the code.

```
#left graph
fig_Sub = plt.figure(1)
fig_Sub.suptitle('Subreddits', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
ax1 = fig_Sub.add_subplot(111)
fig_Sub.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
ax1.set_title('axes title')
ax1.set_xlabel('Word')
y_rotate=ax1.set_ylabel('Instances')
y_rotate.set_rotation(0)
ax1.axis([0, 1000, 0, 1000])
plt.rc('xtick', color='k', labelsize='medium', direction='out')
plt.rc('xtick.major', size=10, pad=100) #size of tick, interval
plt.rc('xtick.minor', size=10, pad=100)

#right graph
fig_user = plt.figure(2)
fig_user.suptitle('Users', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
ax2 = fig_user.add_subplot(111)
fig_user.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
ax2.set_title('axes title')
ax2.set_xlabel('Word')
y2_rotate=ax2.set_ylabel('Instances')
y2_rotate.set_rotation(0)
ax2.axis([0, 1000, 0, 1000])
plt.rc('xtick', color='k', labelsize='medium', direction='out')
plt.rc('xtick.major', size=0, pad=0)
plt.rc('xtick.minor', size=0, pad=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is `pad=100` used for? Can you remove it and from the result explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, removing it fixed the extra space issue underneath the x-axis. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Per @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, get rid of pad in plt.rc().